# mysql query to get highest score

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement of a query which i need to build it contains two tables and top three max records from the  joined columns let me share the requirements first.

return the first,second and third scorer against each category columns to show are

```
category,student_id,name,college_name and score 
order by category ascending and college_name ascending
```

**schema**

```
create table students(
id INT autoincrement,
name varchar(255),
college_name varchar(255)
)

create table participations(
participant_id INT autoincrement,
student_id INT,
category varchar(255)
score INT
)
```

this is what i've done so far

```
select participations.CATEGORY , STUDENTS.id , STUDENTS.name,STUDENTS.college_name
, participations.category ,participations.score
from students
inner join participations on participations.student_id=students.id
order by participations.CATEGORY asc
```

while this query works i'm not getting the expected output. the issues are listed below

not getting only the first , second and third highest score against college(the above query shows all colleges and score)

**sample data!**
[image]

**expected output!**
**[image: Expected Input]**

Can Anyone help me out?

Comment: you need a row_number for this also provide a [mre] please including version

Comment: Where did you implement te `top three max` in your query?  I would have expected the use of, at least,  one of the following items: [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_max)  or [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: I did actuallly bu they were throwing errors, the above query is the one that works and also i wasnt sure which part of the query to put the limit

Comment: Hi @uneebmeer is it possible to provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @RahulBiswas sorry for that i have updated question with sample data and required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DENSE_RANK() because same marks can get multiple students per category.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT p.category
     , s.id student_id
     , s.name student_name
     , s.college_name
     , p.score
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (SELECT category
                 , student_id
                 , score
                 , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY score DESC) row_num
            FROM participations) p
        ON s.id = p.student_id
       AND row_num <= 3
ORDER BY p.category
       , p.row_num;
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34188b3b46b703299a47322f8da6647e

Comment: Hi @uneebmeer please check my query and let me know if any question regard this. Try to write this on the fly.

Comment: unknow column p.category!

Comment: @uneebmeer is category columns existed in participants table?

Comment: yes it does, the original error was "every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: sorry for that i had a typo

Answer (score 0):

Try `DESC LIMIT 3` instead of asc.

let me know whether this worked or not.